# Random variable notation

Tags: probability, random-variables

I saw different notations for both discrete and continuous random variables considering different sources.

1. $X$
2. $\mathrm{x}$

There may be some other notations.
This website adopted the first choice as it seams. Is the second one also allowed since I used to the second notation?

NOTE: This question is possible more suitable to the meta section of this website, I don't quite now, but you can move it.

Comment: I don't think there are fixed rules regarding notation...just be sure you define your variables.  For what it's worth, I'd say notation $\#1$ was more common.  The other just looks like an ordinary variable $x$.

Comment: Yeah but $x$ is different than $\mathrm{x}$. Similarity $\pmb{x}$ is different than both of these.

Comment: Under "notation" in math we more understand some system of symbols, rules for them etc. while $X$ is only variable usually used for random variable.

Comment: @zkutch, this seams to me like a notation problem, because it is not constrained to a particular symbol, but to a group of symbols. It concerns the font style.